# The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs' threw an exception

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I am attempting to create a Windows Forms Application (VS2019, VB.NET, MySQL Connector Net 8.0.23, MySQL.Data v4.5.2, Windows 10) to interface with a remote MySQL server.  I am using the proper server name, username, password and database.  I can connect to the database from this IP address with the same credentials on the same system using MySQL Workbench.  I can also connect to the server and run queries via the Server Explorer in VS2019.

In attempting initial connection using:

```
conn = New MySqlConnection("server=<server>;user=<username>;password=<password>;database=<database>")
conn.Open()
```

I receive an error

```
The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs' threw an exception.

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs' threw an exception.
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs.InitOSDetails()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SetConnectAttrs()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(Boolean reset)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate(String authMethod, Boolean reset)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at KDA_POS.clsDatabase.ConnOpen() in [...]\clsDatabase.vb:line 22
```

Obviously, the most relevant detail is

```
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have searched high and low, but any post with a suggested resolution is too old - it is for VS2017 or older, and using much older versions of MySQL Connector.  It seems pretty clear that there were significant compatibility issues with VS and MySQL in early/mid 2020, and I've seen hints that there were some positive updates since then, but no actual detail.

Has anyone found a way to connect VS2019 VB.NET to MySQL in 2021?  Did I miss a reference or do I need to install System.Management?  Such a dll kinda sounds a bit too important to be missing...  In checking if I can add a reference to System.Management, it does appear to be missing at any version.

Comment: Are you targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core (which includes .NET 5.0)?

Comment: I've tried both - same error

Comment: You can refer to [this reference](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem) to report a problem for Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Since it is MySQL Data that fails, I'd like to confirm whether problem is VS or MySQL - and I've never seen the slightest hint that MS even reads their bug reports.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. solved it by removing mysql.data package and installing mysqlconnector from nuget packages. after adding the using statement in all classes where mysql.data was previously referred everything worked fine